# EF Core: Implement a single endpoint for all Subtypes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, controller, automapper, ardalis-specification

I'm having an issue where I try to make one endpoint for all classes that derive the same class.

One of my Core Entities is called `Cell` and has many deriving types such as `ImageCell`, `VideoCell` and so on.

The project is implemented using `Ardalis.Specification` and `Ardalis.Specification.EntityFrameworkCore`.

For reference here is the base class `Cell` and two deriving classes.
public abstract class Cell : IAggregateRoot

```
namespace Core.Entities.Aggregates
{
    public abstract class Cell : IAggregateRoot
    {
        public int CellId { get; set; }
        public string CellType { get; set; }
        public int RowIndex { get; set; }
        public int ColIndex { get; set; }
        public int RowSpan { get; set; }
        public int ColSpan { get; set; }
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public Page Page { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace Core.Entities.Cells
{
    public class ImageCell : Cell
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace Core.Entities.Cells
{
    public class TextCell : Cell
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All classes have a corresponding `DTO`.

```
namespace API.DTOs
{
    public class CellDTO : DTO
    {
        public int CellId { get; set; }
        public string CellType { get; set; }
        public int RowIndex { get; set; }
        public int ColIndex { get; set; }
        public int RowSpan { get; set; }
        public int ColSpan { get; set; }
        public int PageId { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace API.DTOs.Cells
{
    public class ImageCellDTO : CellDTO
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace API.DTOs.Cells
{
    public class TextCellDTO : CellDTO
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `MappingProfile` is set up according to the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html):

```
namespace API
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            // Entity -> DTO
            ...
            // Cells
            // https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html
            CreateMap<Cell, CellDTO>()
                .IncludeAllDerived();
            CreateMap<ImageCell, ImageCellDTO>();
            CreateMap<AudioTextCell, AudioTextCellDTO>();
            CreateMap<AudioCell, AudioCellDTO>();
            CreateMap<GameCell, GameCellDTO>();
            CreateMap<TextCell, TextCellDTO>();
            CreateMap<VideoCell, VideoCellDTO>();
            ...

            // DTO -> Enitity
            ...
            // Cells
            CreateMap<CellDTO, Cell>()
                .IncludeAllDerived();
            CreateMap<AudioTextCellDTO, AudioTextCell>();
            CreateMap<AudioCellDTO, AudioCell>();
            CreateMap<GameCellDTO, GameCell>();
            CreateMap<TextCellDTO, TextCell>();
            CreateMap<VideoCellDTO, VideoCell>();
            CreateMap<ImageCellDTO, ImageCell>();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The Repository is set up like this:

```
using Ardalis.Specification;
namespace Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
    }
}

using Ardalis.Specification;
namespace Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IReadRepository<T> : IReadRepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
    }
}

namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class EfRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>, IReadRepository<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
        public EfRepository(BookDesinerContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Service like this:

```
namespace Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IService<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
        Task<bool> ExistsByIdAsync(int id);
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
        Task<T> GetByIdAsyncWithSpec(Specification<T> spec);
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync();
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsyncWithSpec(Specification<T> spec);
        Task DeleteByIdAsync(int id);
        Task DeleteRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> range);
        Task<T> AddAsync(T t);
        Task UpdateAsyc(T t);
    }
}
```

Now I created a default implementation:

```
using Ardalis.Specification;
using Core.Interfaces;

namespace Core.Services
{
    public class GenericService<T> : IService<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
        private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;
        private readonly IAppLogger<GenericService<T>> _logger;


        public GenericService(IRepository<T> repository, IAppLogger<GenericService<T>> logger)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<bool> ExistsByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _repository.GetByIdAsync(id) != null;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var t = await _repository.GetByIdAsync(id);
            if (t == null)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Element with id: {id} can not be found!");
                throw new ArgumentException($"Element with id: {id} can not be found!");
            }
            return t;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsyncWithSpec(Specification<T> spec)
        {
            if (!(spec is ISingleResultSpecification))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Specification does not implement marker interface.");
            }
            ISingleResultSpecification<T> specification = (ISingleResultSpecification<T>)spec;
            var t = await _repository.GetBySpecAsync(specification);
            if (t == null)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Element can not be found!");
                throw new ArgumentException($"Element can not be found!");
            }
            return t;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync()
        {
            return await _repository.ListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsyncWithSpec(Specification<T> spec)
        {
            return await _repository.ListAsync(spec);
        }

        public async Task DeleteByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var t = await _repository.GetByIdAsync(id);

            if (t == null)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Element with id: {id} can not be found!");
                throw new ArgumentException($"Element with id: {id} can not be found!");
            }

            await _repository.DeleteAsync(t);
        }

        public async Task DeleteRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> range)
        {
            await _repository.DeleteRangeAsync(range);
        }

        public async Task<T> AddAsync(T t)
        {
            return await _repository.AddAsync(t);
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsyc(T t)
        {
            await _repository.UpdateAsync(t);
        }
    }
}
```

I registered a Service for every single Subtype:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<Cell>, GenericService<Cell>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<ImageCell>, GenericService<ImageCell>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<TextCell>, GenericService<TextCell>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<AudioCell>, GenericService<AudioCell>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<AudioTextCell>, GenericService<AudioTextCell>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<VideoCell>, GenericService<VideoCell>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<GameCell>, GenericService<GameCell>>();
```

And for the final part the controller:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CellsController : BaseController<Cell, CellDTO>
    {
        private readonly IService<ImageCell> _imageCellService;
        private readonly IService<TextCell> _textCellService;
        private readonly IService<AudioCell> _audioCellService;
        private readonly IService<AudioTextCell> _audioTextCellService;
        private readonly IService<VideoCell> _videoCellService;
        private readonly IService<GameCell> _gameCellService;

        public CellsController(
            IService<Cell> service,
            IService<ImageCell> imageCellService,
            IService<TextCell> textCellService,
            IService<AudioCell> audioCellService,
            IService<AudioTextCell> audioTextCellService,
            IService<VideoCell> videoCellService,
            IService<GameCell> gameCellService,
            IMapper mapper) : base(service, mapper)
        {
            _imageCellService = imageCellService;
            _textCellService = textCellService;
            _audioCellService = audioCellService;
            _audioTextCellService = audioTextCellService;
            _videoCellService = videoCellService;
            _gameCellService = gameCellService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public override async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var result = new List<Object>();

            // Add ImageCells
            ICollection<ImageCell> imageCells = (ICollection<ImageCell>)await _imageCellService.ListAsync();
            result.AddRange(_mapper.Map<ICollection<ImageCell>, ICollection<CellDTO>>(imageCells));

            // Add TextCells
            ICollection<TextCell> textCells = (ICollection<TextCell>)await _textCellService.ListAsync();
            result.AddRange(_mapper.Map<ICollection<TextCell>, ICollection<CellDTO>>(textCells));

            ...

            return Ok(result);
        }

        [HttpGet("Page/{pageId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetByPageId(int pageId)
        {
            var result = new List<Object>();

            // Add ImageCells
            ICollection<ImageCell> imageCells = (ICollection<ImageCell>)await _imageCellService.ListAsync();
            result.AddRange(_mapper.Map<ICollection<ImageCell>, ICollection<ImageCellDTO>>(imageCells.Where(c => c.PageId == pageId).ToList()));

            // Add TextCells
            ICollection<TextCell> textCells = (ICollection<TextCell>)await _textCellService.ListAsync();
            result.AddRange(_mapper.Map<ICollection<TextCell>, ICollection<TextCellDTO>>(textCells.Where(c => c.PageId == pageId).ToList()));

           ...

            return Ok(result);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public override async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
        {
            if (await _imageCellService.ExistsByIdAsync(id))
            {
                var result = await _imageCellService.GetByIdAsync(id);

                return Ok(_mapper.Map<ImageCell, ImageCellDTO>(result));
            }

            if (await _textCellService.ExistsByIdAsync(id))
            {
                var result = await _textCellService.GetByIdAsync(id);
                return Ok(_mapper.Map<TextCell, TextCellDTO>(result));
            }

            ...

            return NotFound();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

This is a highly inefficient implementation to my understanding.

Problems:

- I can call /Cells to get all Cells the way it was intended with the `List<Object>`. `List<CellDTO>` always led to a downcast, which was unintended.
  The same problem occures in a DTO that is not shown, that has a `List<CellDTO>` as a property. But I would need the concrete subtypes in this list.

My goals:

- Remove redundant code in the controller
- Only register one `CellSerivce`
- Correct mapping Entity <=> DTO

Things I have considered, but I could not find information to back my thesis:

- Writing a CellSpecification that includes all subtypes
- Creating a DTO that covers all fields from the subtypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```cs
var cells = (ICollection<Cell>)await _cellService.ListAsync();
result.AddRange(_mapper.Map<ICollection<Cell>, ICollection<CellDTO>>(cells));
```

Where `_cellService` is `IService<Cell>`

Comment: As `Cell` is abstract, there will never be "just cells", I would like to access all cells (and subtypes) from `_cellService` if anything.

Comment: If it is Table Per Hierarchy, you can access abstract class via `context.Set<Cell>().ToList()`. EF Core will instantiate all needed classes under hood.

Comment: Where would I set that?

Comment: Set what? By default hierarchy storing is TPH. Have you tried my code?

Comment: It worked after adding eacht Subtype in the OnModelCreating() like `builder.Entity<GameCell>();`